# Jquery, For each looping a List of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, foreach

I have a list of "User" with has Name, Surname and Email.

I need to loop through it on Jquery. This list is returned by a server side method

```
success: function (result) {
                // var res = result.d
                $.each(result, function (index, obj) {
                    alert(obj);
                });

            }
```

Does anyone know how it can be done?

Edit: The entire Ajax list:
        var param = '{"NameofMap":"' + nofm + '", "VillNum":"' + numberV + '"}';

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'GenerateMap.aspx/AddVill',
            type: "POST",
            data: param,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            error: function (msg)
            { alert("Fails"); },
            success: function  (result) {
               $.each(result, function (index) {
                  alert("Test");
               });
            }
        });
```

This is the entire Ajax. It returns a list of Class instances ("User")
It displays "Test" but if I change that with alert(result[index].Name); , it displays just an empty box.

Comment: What `result` looks like?, is your alert getting called?

Comment: What is returned by the server? Can you provide some JSON?

Comment: Edited it to add the Ajax code

Answer (score 4):

As you haven't provide proper information, still you can give this a try.

If you're getting into the `success:` and able to get alert, you can try like this:

You can have properties with it's name

```
--> result.Name
--> result.Surname 
--> result.email
```

So Your code will be like following:

```
$.each(result, function(index) {
     alert(result[index].Name);
     .......
});
```

**Or**

```
$.each(result, function(index, item) {
     alert(item.Name);
     ....... 
});
```

This might help!

Comment: The second param is the object itself, so rather than `result[index].Name`, it could be `$.each(result, function(index, item) {
     alert(item.Name);
     .......
});`

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$.each(data,function(i, item){
 alert(item.name)
});
```

Comment: Doesn't it what OP is currently using?!