# Loop jQuery script for a list of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, leaflet, each

I have the following jQuery script that I need to execute for a long list of objects.

```
$("#ID_001").change(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if(map.hasLayer(ID_001)) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
        map.removeLayer(ID_001);
    } else {
        map.addLayer(ID_001);
        $(this).addClass('selected');
   }
});
```

**What I have done**

Using the following resource:

- [api.jquery.com](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)
- [jquery-loop-for-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22376103/jquery-loop-for-script)
- [jquery-for-each-looping-a-list-of-objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23407338/jquery-for-each-looping-a-list-of-objects)

*I don't think this is a duplicate question of the above as this include an event handler function.*

I have written the following loop but this still doesn't work. I can't understand where is the problem.

```
var obj = {
    "#ID_001": "ID_001",
    "#ID_002": "ID_001"
  };

  $.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
    $(key).change(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if(map.hasLayer(value)) {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
            map.removeLayer(value);
        } else {
            map.addLayer(value);
            $(this).addClass('selected');
       }
    });
  });
```

Can anyone explain to me where is the problem?

**Further details**

The script is a part of LeafLet map control buttons. Chrome DevTool show this message of error when I click on `#ID_001` element, so I think that the problem is that `value` variable doesn't get the proper value.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property '_leaflet_id' on string
> 'L_puntiA'
> at m (Util.js:56)
> at i.hasLayer (Layer.js:211)
> at HTMLInputElement. (mymap_main.js:103)
> at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
> at HTMLInputElement.v.handle (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)

Comment: You use the same value twice for both keys. That might be a problem but hard to tell without a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also you use `ID_001` as a viariable in the first block of code and as a string in the second block.

Comment: Thanks @MarkBaijens, the key fact was that I used ID_001 as variable in the first block and as string in the second. Without the quotes it works! You helped me!

Comment: Glad i could help. Added an answer so this question can be set to resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As sorted out in the comment your problem is that you define the objects with strings instead of variables.

Instead of:

```
var obj = {
  "#ID_001": "ID_001",
  "#ID_002": "ID_001"
};
```

Use:

```
var obj = {
  "#ID_001": ID_001,
  "#ID_002": ID_002
};
```